# How to handle 64-bit signed integer coming from NextJS backend API

Tags: javascript, next.js, integer, long-integer, bigint

I have a NextJS application where one of the backend API routes returns a JSON object that contains a 64-bit signed integer.

```js
// userId is the 64-bit signed integer
res.status(200).json({ id: userId, attributes: userAttributes });
```

When I get the data back in the frontend, I'm having issues parsing the user's ID. When I log it (`console.log(response.data)`) I see something like:

```js
{
    id: { high: 0, low: 1, unsigned: false },
    attributes: { ... }
}
```

I tried parsing using `parseInt` and `BigInt` but it's not working. What's the correct way to use a 64-bit signed integer returned from an API call?

Answer (score 0):

An object with fields `{high, low, unsigned}` appears to be a `Long` from the [Long.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/long) library.

You can either work with it directly (the Long.js library provides a full set of operations, see its documentation), or convert it to a BigInt. Probably (I haven't tested it) that would be something like:

```
function toBigInt(long) {
  let high = long.unsigned ? long.high >>> 0 : long.high;
  return (BigInt(high) << 32n) + BigInt(long.low >>> 0);
}
```